# Ruby and telnet: waitfor doesnt work

Tags: ruby, timeout, telnet

I need to login in a server with Ruby and Telnet and execute a few commands. My actual script is:

```
tn = Net::Telnet::new("Host" => "#{ip}", "Port"  => 23, "Timeout" => 60, 
     "Output_log"=>"output_log.log",
     "Dump_log"=> "dump_log.log",
     "Prompt" => /[#]/ )

tn.cmd("#{USER}\n#{PASS}") { |c| print c }

puts tn.cmd("Conf")
tn.waitfor(/config/) { |str| puts str }
puts tn.cmd("Int fa23")

puts tn.cmd("Shut")
puts tn.cmd("No shut")
puts tn.cmd("Exit")

tn.close
```

I must only execute the second command (`Int fa23`) after the string "config" is found at the output. The problem is that waitfor is not working. Here is the output_log:

```
Trying XX.XX.XX.XX...
Connected to XX.XX.XX.XX.
User Name:username
Password:*************
BOT-SWT-VSAT-AL-...#Conf
BOT-SWT-VSAT-AL-...(config)#
```

The script stops with waitfor time out error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: it's a very interesting script.  my question is, I think, your question:  how do you capture the output?  Or, maybe you just have to process the logs...

Answer (score 0):

Please add the waitfor right after Net::Telnet::new

You should wait for the connection to get established (which happens when creating a Telnet instance) and then wait for the server to respond back every time before sending the next command.

```
        localhost = Net::Telnet::new("Host" => "*****",
                         "Port" => ***, 
                         "Timeout" => 10,
                         "Prompt" => /[$%#>] \z/n)
        localhost.waitfor(/USER/) {
           localhost.cmd("****") { 
              localhost.waitfor(/PASS/) {
                  |c| print c
                  # your next commands
                  ...
                  # localhost.close
              }
           }
        }
```

The key here is to make sure that you have received all the packets from the server (until EOF is received) before responding back. Then sometimes, even consuming/waiting for a space character might count (depending to how your the telnet server is designed).
Then, make sure to set the right regular expression for your match.